# Can I copy a Slate doc?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

There's a slate doc that does almost everything I want to do, but I want to make a copy so that I can make some edits without messing up the original. Is there a way to copy a slate doc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! This is straightforward to do as long as you've got Edit rights on your Slate document.

Simply go into Edit mode and choose the "Actions > Save as" item to clone your Slate document under a different name.

[image: Actions menu in Foundry Slate]